# Rendering variants CSS class

Tags: sxa

I created rendering variants definition which has header, image and button. For the button, I provided CSS class and also uncheck 'Render if empty' checkbox. The issue I am seeing is that if I don't provide value for the button, it still renders. I am using SxA 1.7. Thanks for any help

Comment: In which mode are you checking this? Check if the behaviour is correct in preview/normal mode.

Comment: I am checking this in preview mode and in experience editor. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's working quite fine on 1.7.1. Take a look below:

[image]

And just for the record, this is my Rendering Variant for Page Content:

[image]